# SSMS SQL - Create table with related columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, ssms

I have a DB Diagram with relationships on primary and foreign keys. Then I create a new table in the diagram, with foreign keys to 2 other tables. Example:

Tables in the diagram: Customers, Orders and Status

New table: View (with fk to Customers(CustID), Orders(OrID) and Status(SID))

In view table, I want a column **Ordertype** which should be a related/linked column to Orders table.
Meaning, that whenever I change a value of **Ordertype** in my new **View** table, it gets updated in the Orders table as well.

How can I achieve this? I guess I need sql script that adds such a related column to my view table.

What I have tried:
Relationship Orders(PK) and View(FK) has update property set to "Cascade".
Given same column name and datatype to Ordertype in both tables, Orders and View
But, this doesn't work for me.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you might have an XY problem. A view (bad name for any table BTW) is just a view of data over 1 or more tables. Tell us the actual problem you are trying to solve, not your perceived solution to your original problem.

Comment: @MitchWheat table name is trivial. The actual problem: I am developing an app that works best with 1 table (which is my view table) on sql db. When I update a record from the app, I want the updates to flow through all the related tables in the db. This is what Im trying to solve. I dont want to reference all the related tables in the app. I want this to be handled by the sql server

Comment: NO, tables names are not trivial. Just like variable naming they help you to think about the domain accurately and make things easier to understand and maintain. . You have a design flaw.

Comment: "I am developing an app that works best with 1 table " - that makes ZERO sense. That sounds like you are really saying, that you don't know how to update multiple tables in the app.....

Comment: @MitchWheat any help would be appreciated. Table naming and updating multiple tables from the app is out of context here. 
I would love the server to handle any updates.

Comment: "Table naming and updating multiple tables from the app is out of context here" - No, it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign key constraints can't help you to update data. You could try to use DML Trigger.
For example,

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertUpdateTrigger ON View
AFTER Insert, Update AS 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE O
    SET O.OrderType = I.OrderType 
    FROM ORDERS O 
    JOIN INSRTED I on O.orid = I.id(change to your id)
END
```

Comment: That worked for me! This approach was what I was looking for - automation on event triggers in the data. Thanks